# Looking for a tool to backup and replace file in multiple directories

Tags: backup, file-synchronization, windows-server

I am looking for a tool that can replace a particular file in multiple directories on a server while keeping a backup.

For example:

I have a file ABC.jpg that I want to replace in multiple directories. So I would set the parameters like:

**Source:**

`C:\SourceFolder\`

**File:**

`ABC.jpg`

**Destination:**

```
1. C:\Folder1\
2. C:\Folder2\
etc
```

The tool would then create a backup of file present in every destination folder like "**ABC_Backup_CurrentDate.jpg**" and replace the original one with the one in source location.

Is there any software that can do this ? I would buy it if required. Software should work on Windows Server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at something like [RSync](https://rsync.samba.org/) or [RSnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) which is based on RSync anyway.

Rsnapshot will do this out of the box for you. RSync as well but may require a little scripting. Getting the above to run would require [CygWin](https://www.cygwin.com) or there are Windows binaries out there if you look hard enough.

If command line stuff is not something you feel comfortable with then have a look at something like [FinalBuilder](https://www.finalbuilder.com/finalbuilder) which will allow you to build up your scripting visually. And if you want a copy tool that is Windows native then investigate [xcopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254(v=ws.11).aspx) or [RoboCopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

AJC Sync will do this for you out of the box.  This is software that I created.
You can setup a sync project with multiple sync pairs.  Each sync pair will have the source on the left side and the destination on the right side.  Then you turn on the optional archiving and it will archive the files overwritten during the sync.  The archives are very compact because they only store the changes to the file in a compressed way.  See:
[AJC Sync](http://www.ajcsoft.com/file-sync.htm)

Contact support if you need any assistance.